# Given that $\log_a3 = p$ and $\log_a2 = q$, find an expression for $\log_a4.5a^2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I'm not sure how to do this question. A walkthrough would be appreciated.

> Given that $\log_a3 = p$ and $\log_a2 = q$, find an expression for
> $\log_a4.5a^2$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $\displaystyle 4.5=\frac{3^2}{2}$.
Also, for all $x,y>0$: $$\log_a(xy)=\log_a(x)+\log_a(y),\\\log_a\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)=\log_a(x)-\log_a(y).$$
and
$$\log_a(a)=1.$$

You should be able to conclude.

Comment: Please do no not answer questions that do not meet the quality standards, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards

Comment: @Gary even if I answer with a two-word hint and a list of well known properties?

Comment: Consider it as a suggestion for next time.